# Automatically change format of protected methods

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to use Mathematica for building complex derivatives for my Fortran code. Therefore I have to do some wild string replacements to make that work. Anyway, I got quite far already but now it would come in handy if I could automatically overwrite let's say the `Power` method.

What I want is that Mathematica should replace e.g. `x^(1/4)` with `x**z14` on `FortranForm`. What does work is this:

```
i=1;
j=4;
Unprotect[Power];
Power /: Format[Power[x_, i/j], FortranForm]:=x^ToExpression["z" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]  
Protect[Power];

ToString[Power[x, i/j], FortranForm]
```

This will give `x**z14` as expected.

If I try to automate the process for more fractions

```
Unprotect[Power];
For[i = 1, i <= 9, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 9, j++,
  If[j > 1 && j != i && Mod[i, j] != 0,
    Power /: Format[Power[x_, i/j], FortranForm]:=x^ToExpression["z"<> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]];
    ,Null
  ]
 ]
]
Protect[Power];

ToString[Power[x, i/j], FortranForm]
```

I get `x**z1010` instead?

Can anyone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the variables `i` and `j` on the RHS of the definition are not being bound to the input. A simpler example:

```
i=1; j=4;
foo[i/j] := {i, j}

DownValues[foo]
```

> {HoldPattern[foo[1/4]] :> {i, j}}

You could workaround this by using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With) to inject the values of `i` and `j` into the RHS, but why aren't you using patterns instead? For example:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[Power[x_, Rational[i_, j_]], FortranForm] := x^ToExpression["z"<>ToString[i]<>ToString[j]]
Protect[Power];
```

Then:

```
ToString[x^(3/4), FortranForm]
ToString[x^(1/7), FortranForm]
```

> "x**z34"
>
> "x**z17"

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this! I already thought that my approach is a bit weird. I’ll test it for my case but from the looks this is what I was looking for. I’ll rate your answer as soon as I’ve completed the tests.